# Am I giving Content or Memory address, Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have two different NSArray objects, lets say -

```
NSArray* a and NSArray* b
```

Array b is used to store textual content from csv file.

Now. if I do an operation like the following:

```
a = b;
```

Am I copying the content of b to a or am I making a point to b? In the former case, changes made to array a won't be reflected in array b. On the other hand, in the latter case, they will be.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a memory address (reference).

If you are coming from C development, you should know that the star `*` near the NSArray type means it is a pointer type. This is the same in Objective-C.
*(If you don't know C and this stuff about pointers, just forget it, as every object type in ObjC is a pointer, it is quite transparent to the final coder)*

If you want to create an **independant copy** of `b`, so that modifying `a` does not modify b then, **use the `copy` method**. (If you do, don't forget to release it later, as any `alloc/retain/copy` have to be balanced by a `release/autorelease` call at the end)

Note anyway that **an `NSArray` is immutable by construct**, meaning that there is no method in the `NSArray` class to modify its content. So for your exact example, pointing to the same `NSArray` (without making a deep copy) is **not really a problem as you can't modify an `NSArray`**.

This is starting to become an issue only if you use a `NSMutableArray`, that do have methods to modify their contents.
When working with mutable classes like `NSMutableArray`, you then should use `mutableCopy` to have a mutable copy (instead of `copy` which returns an immutable object)

Let me illustrate this in the following example:

```
NSMutableArray* a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c"];
NSMutableArray* b = a; // points to the same object as a
NSArray* c = [[a copy] autorelease]; // immutable copy
NSMutableArray* d = [[a mutableCopy] autorelease]; // mutable copy, independant with a

// Now if you modify a...
[a addObject:@"d"];
// ...then b is also modified (it is the same object)
// but c and d aren't.
[d addObject:@"independant"];
// this does only modify d, but neither a, b or c.
// [c addObject:@"illegal"]; // <-- can't do this, addObject is a method of NSMutableArray, non-existing on NSArray.
```

Comment: *(Note: Answer edited to add sample code and special considerations concerning mutable/immutable classes)*

Comment: superb answer with real nice examples. one up

Answer (score 3):

Just the address.

If you want a copy you'd have to do something like:

```
a = [b copy];
```

Answer (score 2):

Both a and b are 'pointers' to the memory address.  When you assign a to the value of b, they are just now both pointing to the same memory address.

For more information on pointers:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HowToUsePointers

Answer (score 1):

Just memory address. There are explicit methods for you to create a copy of that array. However a simple assignment as above will not result in copying.

In C terms, both pointers are pointing to the same memory address.